# ExtJS: How to group items in combo box, but then show all detail records in display text

Tags: extjs, data-binding, grouping

Using ExtJS 6.x. I have the following Fiddle:
[bind grouped combo box value to detail displayfield](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/289h&view/editor)

To start with: I would like to show just a single instance of each item in the combo box instead of the multiple instances that show up for each item (thus, instead of "one" and "two" showing up multiple times, I only want these to appear once in the combo box). Is there a way to do the grouping within the viewModel to achieve this?

Assuming then that the combobox items are now grouped accordingly, I then want to show the details in the displayText area, so that for example, if I choose "one" from the combo box, the detail area would show ALL the ids associated with this, those being '1' and '2'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, although it feels a bit kludgey:

First, I created an SQL view with the records grouped together (using a unique key of "name + code")... then, I created another SQL view where "name + code" was another field for the original table.

I then used associations in my models to link these two entities together, and thus, used data bindings to link the record selected in the combobox to a grid.